# how to properly animate/tween a line in THREE.js using TweenLite?

Tags: javascript, three.js, gsap

I want to tween a 3D line using `THREE.JS` and `TweenLite`. But the approach that works well with e.g. the position of a sphere does not work out here. I do not know why.

```
            // add a line to the scene using THREE.js
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(500, 500, 500));
            var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial());
            scene.add( line );  

            // using TweenLite to animate
            var tl = new TimelineLite();          
            var target = { x: 0, y: 0, z:0 };
            line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
            tl.add(TweenLite.to(line.geometry.vertices[1] , 1, target));
            tl.play();
```

**Result**: Nothing happens. Why?

PS. The reason might be explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578509/how-to-draw-three-js-line-geometry-with-tween-animation-effect), but I do not understand it.

Answer (score 6):

Found the solution myself: Above the vertex is flagged as needing an update, which happens once in the line `line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;`. But this flag needs to be set **after each change** in the vertex. This can be achieved by putting the update line in the `onUpdate` function. Now, the line will be called after each update of the vertex.

```
target.onUpdate = function () {
   line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
};
```

Comment: Should be noted that the onUpdate function is a function that comes with GSAP, not Three.js, for clarity purposes.

Comment: You hardcoded the animation a one specific vertice. Did you also find a way to animate all vertices of an object? That's what I am struggling atm because a simple forEach iteration doesn't seems to work.